# The best way to get a data frame from user in shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app where I want the user to enter a few (but variable number of) rows of a data frame (with 3 columns). The best way would be to have the user enter a row at a time, and perhaps push a button to create a new row.

What is an intuitive way to implement this in a shiny gui?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
# Sample data
my_data <- data.frame(matrix(1,nrow=1,ncol=3))
colnames(my_data) <- c("one","two","three")
emptry_row <- as.data.frame(matrix(1,nrow=1,ncol=3))
colnames(emptry_row) <- colnames(my_data)

ui =fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(actionButton("add_row", "Add a row")),
  mainPanel(dataTableOutput("my_table"))
)

server = function(input, output, session){

  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- my_data

  newEntry <- observe({
    if(input$add_row > 0) {
      isolate(values$df <- rbind(values$df, emptry_row))
    }
  })
  output$my_table <- renderDataTable({
    if(input$add_row==0){return(values$df)}
    values$df
  })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```